# Enforcing uniqueness in 5 combo boxes with the same values

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm working on a Dungeons & Dragons text adventure using the 5th Edition ruleset, I'm currently working a form for allocating Ability Scores. But for those who aren't familiar with D&D, here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have 6 values (15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8) which the player will allocate to six stats (Strength, Dexterity, Constitution, Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma). The player will see six read-only textboxes each containing one of the number values. Next to each is a combo box containing all six stat names. The player must select which stat they'd like each number to be assigned to.

Multiple numbers cannot be assigned to the same stat. So to demonstrate, this is correct: [correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fokhH.png)

and this is incorrect: [incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNDJj.png)

How do I enforce each combo box to be unique from all the others?

Comment: Have you tried putting in a check during `_OnChangedEvent` for the comboBoxes?

Comment: Remove preceding selections from the lists as they select.  Or just throw away the selection.  Or reverse the process: make the category fixed and present them with each value.

Comment: Actually, I think you have over simplified it - the values can only be picked once too, right?